# Memory Dump from VMWare Workstation 8

Tags: vmware-workstation, dump

My goal is to get a memory dump from a Windows XP guest running inside VMWare Workstation 8.

1. When I tried to to use the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> combo there was no reaction on the screen, no file was created
2. I read [this](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/snapshot2core_technote.pdf) document and found that I can use vmss2core

   2. I suspended the vm
   3. ran `vmss2core.exe WinXP.vmss`

      1. `Unrecognized .vmss file(magic 0)`
   4. ran `vmss2core.exe WinXP.vmem`

      1. `Unrecognized .vmem file(magic f000ff53)`

**Note1:** My guest xp is working fine and I can use it like normal. So there are certainly no issues in the guest.
**Note2:** I am using a USB keyboard (in reference to the first step)
Can someone please show me a way through which I can get a memory dump in VMWare Workstation **8**

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545499.aspx for a USB keyboard, you cannot incite a crash 0xE2 on Windows XP. You will need to switch to a PS/2 keyboard, or use a different (later) version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a .vmem file with the same date and time as the .vmss, then you need to retrieve both.

For instance, to create a WindDbg file (memory.dmp) you could try the next command:

```
vmss2core -W WinXP.vmss WinXMP.vmem
```

More info: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125086